Which weights change when fine-tunning a pre-trained model? (Hugging Face)
I am using the AutoModelForSequenceClassification class to fine-tune a pre-trained model (which originally is based on GPT2 architecture)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("Natooz/Maestro-REMI-bpe20k", trust_remote_code=True, torch_dtype="auto",num_labels=2)

And I am using the basic training loop suggested in the NLP course from hugging face:
model.train()
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for batch in train_dl:
        outputs = model(**batch)
        loss = outputs.loss
        accelerator.backward(loss)

        optimizer.step()
        lr_scheduler.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        progress_bar.update(1)

My question is:
1. Which weights of the model are going to change after using this training loop? Am I training all the weights of the model? Only the classification head added by the AutoModelForSequenceClassification?
It wouldn't make a lot of sense to me for all weights to change, because in theory I wouldn't be "transferring" any knowledge from my pre-trained model to my task.
2. Would it work the same if I fine-tune my pre-trained model with the trainer class instead of the training loop?
Thank you so much in advance!

Answer to your first question: Yes, the entire model will be fine-tuned during the training process and this does not violate "transferring knowledge" because the pre-trained weights will just be updated using the loss/gradient from your fine-tuning process. However, you can freeze some layers during fine-tuning depending on the task, amount of training data, and computational resources.
Answer to your second question: Yes, using the Trainer from the Transformers library would work similarly. The Trainer class is just a higher-level abstraction that handles the training process for you.
